# JQ DataTable setting Ajax call headers

Tags: datatables

I am using `jq datatable`, I want to send a `token` in `JQ DataTable ajax` request `header`.
Just like a regular ajax call like this

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,            // data I want to post at server
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        'Token': Token     //token I want to send in ajax header
    },
    cache: false,
    async: async,
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    complete: function () {
    },
    success: function (user, status, XHR) {
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I am a little confused - do you mean jQuery dataTables or jqx DataTable? The example is very sparse, what is the context?

Comment: @davidkonrad I am talking about jqdatatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this usefull. [JqDataTable how to add authorization header to ajax requests.](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17063/how-to-add-authorization-header-to-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 3):

you can add it in `beforeSend`, so your `ajax` would look something like this:

```
"ajax": {
            "url"  : 'changeToYourUrl',
            "type" : 'POST/GET',
            "beforeSend" : function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('TOKEN',token);
            }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: how can I do it in datatable ajax request.

Comment: you mean http://www.datatables.net/? that is how I added csrf token to my ajax calls. Instead of ajax:url change it to what I posted here or post your initialization code.